# Python: printing dictionary values in a function

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

So I've been trying to get this to work for a while. I'm trying to get these dictionaries to list all the values in the two dictionaries through a function, if that makes sense. It runs however it only prints the line of the final values of the two dictionaries.

```
 dictionary = {
    "grades": "O",
    "grades": "E",
    "grades": "A",
    "grades": "P",
    "grades": "D",
    "grades":"T",
}
dictionary_means = {
    "means": "O is for Outstanding!  You're top level now!",
    "means": "E is for Exceeds Expectations!  Very well done, almost 
perfect!",
    "means": "A for Acceptable.  That's okay, hopefully it'll get you 
somewhere...",
    "means": "P is for Poor.  Is that the best you can do?",
    "means": "D is for Dreadful.  Well at least it's not T...",
    "means": "T is for Troll.  Wow, you're an idiot."
}
def owls_grades (grades):
    for v in grades.values():
        print("Your grade is {}. ".format(v))




def owls_means (means):
    for value in means.values():
        print ("{}".format(value))

print (owls_grades(dictionary))
print (owls_means(dictionary_means))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are duplicating your dictionary keys, thus overwriting the value each time you repeat a key.

Here is an example to demonstrate that you cannot duplicate a dictionary key.

```
d = {'A': 1, 'A': 2}

print(d)  # {'A': 2}
```

Instead, `dictionary_means`, by example, should look like this.

```
dictionary_means = {
    "O": "O is for Outstanding!  You're top level now!",
    "E": "E is for Exceeds Expectations!  Very well done, almost 
perfect!",
    "A": "A for Acceptable.  That's okay, hopefully it'll get you 
somewhere...",
    "P": "P is for Poor.  Is that the best you can do?",
    "D": "D is for Dreadful.  Well at least it's not T...",
    "T": "T is for Troll.  Wow, you're an idiot."
}
```

As for `dictionary`, it seems a `dict` is not the data structure you want. Use a `list` instead if you goal is to list allowed grade values.

```
["O", "E", "A", "P", "D", "T"]
```

Comment: I didn't know that you couldn't use the same keys in a dictionary.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, okay I'll defiantly mark it as accepted.  One question though if you don't mind.  If instead used a list for the grade values and dictionary with values.  How do I combine them when a call them?

Comment: @MikaLand If you want to print the grades out of a list, your function can actually look like this: `def owls_grades (grades): print(*grades)`. Or if you don't like, or don't know about this syntax yet, just remove the .values from your existing function.

Comment: Like *args or would it be **kwargs?

Comment: I encourage you to try it. One will work, the other wont

Comment: Okay will do.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the dictionaries which are defined, are having same keys. 
Dictionaries in Python is treated as “associative arrays”. Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be keys. Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a key. You can’t use lists as keys since lists can be modified in place using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like append() and extend().

The idea behind using dictionary was to have a quick search, instead of sequential search. You should have a unique key with which you can search for the key to get the corresponding value. And if defining the same key with different values, the purpose of using the dictionary is defeated.

```
>>>
>>> dictionary = { 'key1' : 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> dictionary['key1']
'value1'
>>> dictionary['key2']='value21'
>>> dictionary
{'key2': 'value21', 'key1': 'value1'}
>>>
```